# Things every DBA for DB2 on Unix, Linux should know

Tags: database, database-administration, db2

What are the most useful resources for a DB2 DBA working on Unix or Linux?

- Books
- Web sites
- Tools
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

http://freedb2.com/ of course :)

Answer (score 0):

DB2 Handbook
serverfault url
stackoverflow url
DB2 Management tools

Answer (score 0):

http://www.lazydba.com is my favorite site for DB2-related information.

The IBM docs are actually quite good as well:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

If you need UNIX implementation-specific syntax the Rosetta Stone for UNIX is handy:
http://www.bhami.com/rosetta.html

Answer (score 0):

[www.db2bookmarks.com](http://www.db2bookmarks.com) < -- this collection of links is great...

Answer (score 0):

www.channeldb2.com - videos from big names in UDB industry,
IDUG - International DB2 Users Group

Answer (score 0):

http://it.toolbox.com/people/katsnelson/posts/blogs/ - Leon Katnelson - IBM prog director's blog

Answer (score 0):

http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/db2-l/  - db2 list from ITToolbox

Answer (score 0):

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.databases.ibm-db2/topics?lnk=rgh&pli=1 - IBM Db2 - google group - my last resort and steady saviour at times of need.

Answer (score 0):

Check out an expanding selection of courses on http://DB2University.com. While selection is limited now, it will grow rapidly.